# Mongo - Create custom _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So currently when one of my documents is made, Mongo generates a random `ObjectId`. However I would like this to be a value of my choosing. I am using postman to test this and if I create a new document and specify a value for `_id` then it ignores it and overwrites it with the one that Mongo generates.

I am using node to define my schema and I haven't declared an `_id` field, is that what I must do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bydefault Mongodb will generate `_id` of Type `ObjectId` ,
in mongoose if you not define `_id` field , it will take `_id` of type `ObjectId`

if you want to add _id field by your self , you need to define like this in your mongoose model schema

```
_id: {
    type: Number
  }
```

Comment: Then this appears in my console when I do this and save `Cannot specify a custom index on '_id' for model name "Contractor", MongoDB does not allow overwriting the default '_id' index`